# node js express, creating one class and use in different routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm creating apis in the routes folder in my project, how do I create a class that does the validation in and use it in all the routes.
for example if the route creates a new user and I want my validation class to make sure the a certain object isn't empty, not error, not undefined not null.

for example I want use the class to validate if the is not empty
I'm already using express validator (req.assert) but I was asked to change to a class.

How do I use other classes in my route and how do I force node to bring the data before continuing the app

```
   router.post('/add',function(req,res){
   var record = req.body.record,
    first_name = record.first_name,
    middle_name = record.middle_name,
    last_name = record.last_name,
    phone_number = record.phone_number;


     })
```

Comment: Do you use [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/)?

Comment: am using mongoose and mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using Express, you can create a middleware and then `use` it on your app to apply it to all your routes :

A middleware is just a function with the following signature : `function(req, res, next){}`. In your case, you could do :

```
function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  if (req.body.record)
    next()
  else
    res.status(400).json({message: "No record in your body"});  
}
```

The `next` function, provided by Express, allows you to 'continue', go to the next middleware or route. The flow of the information looks like that :

```
request recieved by the route --> middleware1 --> middleware2 --> ... --> response
```

Say that all the routes are composed by middlewares and the one with `res.json` or `res.send` will be our 'final route', the one that will return a response.

So .. In your case, if you want to apply this middleware to all your routes, you can do :

```
app.use(myMiddleware)
```

Or, if you want to use it on your route only :

```
router.post('/add', myMiddleware, function(req,res){ ... });
```

If you want to apply it to all routes with a certain prefix, do the following :

```
var router = express.Router()
router.use(myMiddleware)
app.use('/record', router)
```

Hope it helps,
cheers